# how to submit many mapreduce jobs in one terminal?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, job-scheduling

I am using mapreduce to run the program, to submit one job: 
I can use following format
./hadoop jar program.jar arguments

in one terminal, this can submit one job, but what if I want to submit 100 jobs? impossible to
open 100 terminals
so I am seeking a batch job submitting methods, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call ToolRunner.run(..) in a loop within your main method. Be sure to amend your Tool instance to call `Job.submit()` rather than `Job.waitForCompletion()` - ensuring your jobs run more in parallel rather than sequentially (you're still limited to how many jobs you can run in parallel by your cluster size / config):

```
public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      ToolRunner.run(new MyDriver(), args);
    }
  }

  public int run(String args) {
    Job job = new Job(getConf());

    // job set up
    // ...

    job.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: the above example assume that the args is fixed right? what if I want to pass different args to the different job? thanks

Comment: just create a new args array for each loop iteration, and amend the contents as required

Comment: It seems to me that this way, can not fulfill my task, it will finish one job, then submit another one, which means submit the job sequentially, while I want to submit job parallely, right?

Comment: sorry because I use the job.waitForCompletion(true)  instead of job.submit, so it is my problem, your solution can submit many jobs in parallel

Comment: @ChrisWhite : I am ok with your solution. But can i get the counter values of each submitted job once each of the job has completed?